# Ubuntu mate17:04 not shutting down correctly

Tags: suspend, shutdown

I have read the problems with 16:04 etc not shutting down correctly. 
I think this problem is slightly different. I had ubuntu 15 for a longtime then upgraded to 17 
All was well with 17 but unfortunately I had a hard disk failure. I have now replaced the hard drive and re-installed 17:04

The problem now is that on shut down the laptop (Toshiba L50) hangs at the last part of shutting and I have to press and hold the power button.
I have also noticed it doesn't suspend on shutting the lid. It all worked before on this laptop with its original drive.

I checked the bios settings and they haven't changed.
I first noticed it after the install process had completed and i removed the CD and pressed enter.
Any help is appreciated.
swlr

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work.
I was wrong with the bios changing. When i changed the hard drive I remember the date and time had to be re entered on re inserting the battery. It must have gone to default. anyway I remember reading someone had changed the USB settings. I did the same and it is now operating. No idea why the USB support should cause this ?
swlr